# Box2D & EaselJS, setTransform returns an error

Tags: box2d, easeljs, createjs

I have the following code to manually set the position of a (dynamic) object in a Box2D world (drawn with the help of EaselJS).
Unfortunately `setTransform` returns this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined
```

This is the code

```
// during drag and drop
if(mouseJoint & isMouseDown) {
    mouseJoint.SetTarget(new b2Vec2(mouseX, mouseY));
    var body = mouse.getBodyAtMouse();

    if(body != null) {
        body.SetAngularVelocity(0);
        body.SetAngle(0);
        body.SetTransform(b2Vec2(10,10), 0);
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using

```
body.SetPosition(new b2Vec2(10,10));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no JS guru, but I suspect you need to use 'new b2Vec2' instead of just 'b2Vec2', in the same way as you have for the SetTarget call.

Comment: True! I now get "'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a.GetAngle()')", what should I pass as a second argument?